# Paste values in a data frame based on duplicated values in other columns in R

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate, reshape2

I have a data frame as follows

```
dt <- data.frame(genotype = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7",  "X8", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4",
                              "X5", "X6", "X7",  "X8", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7",  "X8"),
                 variable = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                              "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
                 value = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L,  3L, 4L, 5L, 5L,
                           1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L), stringsAsFactors = F)    
dt
   genotype variable value
1        X1        A     1
2        X2        A     1
3        X3        A     2
4        X4        A     3
5        X5        A     4
6        X6        A     5
7        X7        A     6
8        X8        A     7
9        X1        B     1
10       X2        B     2
11       X3        B     3
12       X4        B     3
13       X5        B     3
14       X6        B     4
15       X7        B     5
16       X8        B     5
17       X1        C     1
18       X2        C     2
19       X3        C     3
20       X4        C     4
21       X5        C     5
22       X6        C     6
23       X7        C     7
24       X8        C     8
```

I want to create a new column by pasting together genotype data according to duplication in value column within each variable.

The desired output as follows.

```
out <- data.frame(genotype = c("X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7",  "X8", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4",
                           "X5", "X6", "X7",  "X8", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7",  "X8"),
              variable = c("A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "B", "B", "B", "B", 
                           "B", "B", "B", "B", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), 
              value = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
                        5L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L),
              lab = c("X1, X2", "X1, X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8", "X1", 
                      "X2", "X3, X4, X5", "X3, X4, X5", "X3, X4, X5", "X6", "X7, X7", 
                      "X8, X7", "X1", "X2", "X3", "X4", "X5", "X6", "X7", "X8"), stringsAsFactors = F)
out
genotype variable value        lab
1        X1        A     1     X1, X2
2        X2        A     1     X1, X2
3        X3        A     2         X3
4        X4        A     3         X4
5        X5        A     4         X5
6        X6        A     5         X6
7        X7        A     6         X7
8        X8        A     7         X8
9        X1        B     1         X1
10       X2        B     2         X2
11       X3        B     3 X3, X4, X5
12       X4        B     3 X3, X4, X5
13       X5        B     3 X3, X4, X5
14       X6        B     4         X6
15       X7        B     5     X7, X7
16       X8        B     5     X8, X7
17       X1        C     1         X1
18       X2        C     2         X2
19       X3        C     3         X3
20       X4        C     4         X4
21       X5        C     5         X5
22       X6        C     6         X6
23       X7        C     7         X7
24       X8        C     8         X8
```

I have tried to use `aggregate` as follows, but failing to get desired result as the duplicated values are lost.

```
cons <- aggregate(. ~value+variable, data=dt,
                  function(x) paste(unique(x), collapse = ","))
cons
   value variable genotype
1      1        A    X1,X2
2      2        A       X3
3      3        A       X4
4      4        A       X5
5      5        A       X6
6      6        A       X7
7      7        A       X8
8      1        B       X1
9      2        B       X2
10     3        B X3,X4,X5
11     4        B       X6
12     5        B    X7,X8
13     1        C       X1
14     2        C       X2
15     3        C       X3
16     4        C       X4
17     5        C       X5
18     6        C       X6
19     7        C       X7
20     8        C       X8
```

How to get the desired output preferably in base R ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can easily do it with `dplyr`.

```
library(dplyr)

dt %>% group_by(variable, value) %>%
  mutate(lab = toString(genotype)) %>%
  as.data.frame()

#    genotype variable value        lab
# 1        X1        A     1     X1, X2
# 2        X2        A     1     X1, X2
# 3        X3        A     2         X3
# 4        X4        A     3         X4
# 5        X5        A     4         X5
# 6        X6        A     5         X6
# 7        X7        A     6         X7
# 8        X8        A     7         X8
# 9        X1        B     1         X1
# 10       X2        B     2         X2
# 11       X3        B     3 X3, X4, X5
# 12       X4        B     3 X3, X4, X5
# 13       X5        B     3 X3, X4, X5
# 14       X6        B     4         X6
# 15       X7        B     5     X7, X8
# 16       X8        B     5     X7, X8
# 17       X1        C     1         X1
# 18       X2        C     2         X2
# 19       X3        C     3         X3
# 20       X4        C     4         X4
# 21       X5        C     5         X5
# 22       X6        C     6         X6
# 23       X7        C     7         X7
# 24       X8        C     8         X8
```

**Edited:** As suggested by `@markus` one can use `transform` function in `base-R`

```
 transform(dt, lab = ave(genotype, variable, value, FUN = toString))
```

Comment: In `base R`: `transform(dt, lab = ave(genotype, variable, value, FUN = toString))` or using `data.table`: `library(data.table); setDT(dt)[, lab := toString(genotype), by = .(variable, value)]`

Answer (score 3):

There is nothing wrong with `aggregate` as long as you follow it with `merge` in order to recover the duplicate rows.

```
res <- aggregate(genotype ~ variable + value, dt, paste, collapse = ", ")
res <- merge(dt, res, by = c("value", "variable"))[-3]
names(res)[3] <- "genotype"

head(res, 15)
#   value variable   genotype
#1      1        A     X1, X2
#2      1        A     X1, X2
#3      1        B         X1
#4      1        C         X1
#5      2        A         X3
#6      2        B         X2
#7      2        C         X2
#8      3        A         X4
#9      3        B X3, X4, X5
#10     3        B X3, X4, X5
#11     3        B X3, X4, X5
#12     3        C         X3
#13     4        A         X5
#14     4        B         X6
#15     4        C         X4
```